# PHP , MSSql server connection timeout

Tags: php, sql-server, connection-timeout

I have a question please help me.
I want to connect mssql server using php, I want to set a time limit of 15 seconds. I want to check if the database is reachable in 15 sec. 
I tried using the following code but not working.
I dont want to do this by doing server level changes in php.ini file. 
I want to do this by php only.

```
ini_set('mssql.connect_timeout',15);
connection = mssql_connect($_POST['DB_HOST'],$_POST['DB_USER'],$_POST['DB_PASS']);
if(!$connection) {
    throw new Exception('Unable to connect database');
} else {
    $database = mssql_select_db($_POST['DB_NAME'], $connection);
    if(!$database)  {
        throw new Exception('Unable to select database');
    } else {
        echo "Connected";
    }
}
```

Comment: see it:

set_time_limit(0);   
ini_set('mysql.connect_timeout','0');   
ini_set('max_execution_time', '0');

Answer (score 1):

while setting the set_time_limit(), the duration of sleep() will be ignored in the execution time. The following illustrates:

```
<?php
echo '<html><body>';
set_time_limit(1);
$i = 0;
while($i++ < 100000001){
        if($i % 100000 == 0){
                echo $i / 100000, "<br/>\n";
        }
}
echo "done.<br/>\n";

// will not echo 'done.'.
?>
```

Want more info see here:-
http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php

Comment: Dear Arunendra, you  are not getting my point, actually I just want to check if my database is reachable or not in 15 secs only for a particular page only

Answer (score 1):

You can initilize local settings in a php file.
You can set values like max_execution_time, default_socket_timeout, memory_limit, mysql.connect_timeout, user_ini.cache_ttl, display_errors and log_errors
it always nice to check the errors in PHP files with error_reporting.

Below is the sample script to set ini_set values.

If you dont want to set every time in PHP script simply set the values in php.ini file on your server/machine.

```
<?php  
ini_set('max_execution_time', 6000);  
ini_set("default_socket_timeout", 6000);  
ini_set('memory_limit','256M');   
ini_set('mysql.connect_timeout', 6000);  
ini_set('user_ini.cache_ttl', 6000);  
ini_set('display_errors',0);    
ini_set('log_errors',1);    
error_reporting(E_ALL);    
//phpinfo();
```

Comment: Dear Navnish, I am doing the same in the above code but its not working